# Get Birthday Information using user.birthday.read scope

Tags: google-docs-api

We have followed the steps mentioned as per the https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow. But while trying to fetch the date of birth information using 'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read', we are getting payload as below:

payload{"at_hash":"-mvIlEROpJsQSF9rQpRDfA","aud":"<CLIENT_ID>","azp":""<CLIENT_ID>"","email":"sample@gmail.com","email_verified":true,"exp":1628092721,"iat":1628089121,"iss":"https://accounts.google.com","sub":"108685651390298470023","name":"mnbvc plm","picture":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwejAC1r2SasgNdtqpd6f5q_Ih2-vDiTxELWDhg=s96-c","given_name":"mnbvc","family_name":"plm","locale":"en-GB"}

Please find below the index.html file we are using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<CLIENT_ID>">
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer>
  </script>
 
<script>
  function myFunction() {
 auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(signInCallback);
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
 
 <script>
 function renderButton() {
     gapi.signin2.render('signinButton', {
       'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
       'width': 240,
       'height': 50,
       'longtitle': true,
       'theme': 'dark',
       'onsuccess': start
     });
   }
 function start() {
     gapi.load('auth2', function() {
       auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance({
         client_id: '<CLIENT_ID>',
         scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
         access_type: 'offline'
       });
     });
   }
    function signInCallback(authResult) {
     if (authResult['code']) {
var authcode = authResult['code'];
       // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
       $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

       // Send the code to the server
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/gplus.form?authcode='+authcode,
         // Always include an `X-Requested-With` header in every AJAX request,
         // to protect against CSRF attacks.
         headers: {
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
         },
         contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
         success: function(result) {
           // Handle or verify the server response.
         },
         processData: false,
         data: authResult['code']
       });
     } else {
       // There was an error.
     }
    }
  </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

What else change is required at JAVA side to get the birthday information?

Comment: suggestion: you can add code fences to format your payload code and make it more readable.